# bootstrap align form/selects with nav tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a tab menu that has 2 select options to the far right of the menu.

Below is the basics of what I have but I can't seem to get the selects to float all the way to the right.

Any thoughts? I know it is probably the nav-item preventing me from doing it but I want to keep the bottom border that goes all the way across so it appears 'seamless'

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <div class="form-inline text-sm-right">
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            <option>Option 1</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            <option>Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pnfcs4bo/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `float-xs-right`..

```
                <li class="nav-item float-xs-right">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            <option>Option 1</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            <option>Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/juUSEhgnKQ

Also, note that `float-xs-right` has changed to `float-right` in the latest Alpha 6.